# How to stream large binary data to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, ado.net, scalability

I have a web service written in ASP.NET MVC with a SQL Server backend.  Clients can send large data in calls to the web service, in the order of 10's of megabytes each.

On the server side I want to read the HTTP request stream and write it to VARBINARY field in a SQL table.  **How can I do this without reading the entire stream into an in-memory array**?

The reason I am concerned about memory is that this system needs to scale to 1000's of concurrent clients (at least).

I'm currently using Linq to SQL and it doesn't look like it supports streaming of data, because the Linq Binary type can only be initialized using a byte array.

Is there some other way to do this using Linq to SQL?

If this is not possible using Linq to SQL, how can I do this using ADO.NET or some other approach?

Comment: What version are you on? Filestream is recommended rather than storing as blobs inside the data files for data that big.

Comment: @Martin - *what* Filestream? your comment isn't very useful without further elaboration.

Comment: @Peter http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx

Comment: @Peter: some people here assume readers are smart enough to type a term into the documentation's search.

Comment: @Martin At this point I'm trying to figure out how a client can insert data in a memory efficient way.  The Filestream feature in SQL Server appears to address efficient storage and retrieval of large data.  Thanks for bringing this up anyway, I'll probably need to look into this at some point as well.

Comment: @DSO - I believe there are some streaming APIs that may assist what you are doing but haven't used FS myself yet.

Comment: @TomTom - SO have simple wiki-like features that makes it dead simple to add quick-to-read answers with links to related content. Not using these features is just laziness. Also, calling people stupid doesn't make a very constructive argument. In this specific case and context, I can think of at least two `Filestreams`. Is it very useful to require that every reader guess which one @Martin refers to? IMO, no.

Comment: If you're sending the file using an multipart form, and the MVC Request.Files property, then the upload is already in memory, isn't it?  I believe that the entire request would've already have been set, or it would be impossible for the framework to know how many files were sent.

Answer (score 2):

You can stream the data to disk, and then use [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) to perform a bulk import of the data. For example:

```
INSERT INTO YOURTABLE(binaryColumnName) 
SELECT * FROM 
OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\data.bin', SINGLE_BLOB)
```

You can use [temp file APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363875%28VS.85%29.aspx) to avoid having to manage the lifetime of the data on disk ... it will be deleted once no longer in use.

Comment: Not sure if this would be efficient if IIS and SQL Server are on deployed on different boxes, as I would need to store the file in a share.

Comment: That's kind of what the FileStream support in SqlServer.  The client transmits the data over SMB to the sql server, sql server manages the data wherever it's configured to store it.  The plus is you wouldn't have to save the file on the web server, and then transport it to the sql server. Sql server also manages security on the fly based on sql server rules.  The cons is that you have to allow windows auth, and have no firewall restriction between your web server and sql server for SMB.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the .WRITE clause of the UPDATE statement to do chunked data insertion.  If you're using LINQ, you'd create two commands from the data context object.  First one to create (INSERT) the row that will contain the data.  The second one would be an UPDATE statement that uses the .WRITE clause.  parameterize the data and offset values.  Loop through, executing the UPDATE statement as many times as you have "chunks".

INSERT INTO XrayImages (HeaderId, ImageBytes) VALUES(@headerId, @imageValue)

UPDATE XrayImages SET ImageBytes.WRITE(@imageChunk, NULL, @chunkLength WHERE ImageId = @imageId;

For more information, please check out this MSDN Article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399384.aspx

---

I'm pretty sure that by the time that your Controller code is called, the entire request has been received (and is in memory).  I'm basing this off that the Request.Files collection already knows how many files are there, and their lengths.  With multi-part forms, the only way I know how to determine this is by reading the entire request.  I don't know of anyway to change this in MVC, so you may have to write a handler that does the actual file upload itself.

There are a lot of variables here that would need to be considered. Depending on the amount of the 1000's of concurrent clients that will be uploading data at once, you'd need multiple GB nics between the db server and web server.  You'd also need I/O capabilities on your database server that would be beyond what I've experienced.

I would seriously consider saving the files to a file system based location and having the meta info in the database, especially if you can keep the files on the web server. Otherwise, i think that using SqlServer's FileStream abilities would be more scalable than just a pure table solution.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm using Request.InputStream which should not be buffering everything into memory.  I am not using Request.Files, as the clients are not using HTML upload feature (the clients are services, not users running web browsers).  You make some good points however, I'll probably need to measure before making any architectural changes.

Comment: A quick possible test would be to do an upload, setting a break point early in the controller's action.  See if the memory usage (should probably use IIS instead of the web development server) increases by the size of the upload. Using a larger file would make this more obvious.